# Putting Telegram in background

Tags: wingpanel, system, thirdpartyapps, flatpak

big noob here

I recently installed Telegram via Flathub to have the updates because the version of the app center is old. However, when i close the app, it can't have the notifications when I recive new messages like before. Is it possible to put Telegram in background process in order to have the notifications ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable the wingpanel notifications? By default elementaryos doesn't allow notifications to third party apps.

In order to enable it for third party apps I recommend you to use these steps.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8S_Z82DDFbo

It worked for me.